# Running Java program via Command Prompt with input and output files

Tags: java, command-line, piping

I have a program that is supposed to take inputs from the commandline and direct them to **standard input** and direct the output to **standard output**. The code supposed to be entered into the commandline is meant to look as follows:

```
java    package.sub.Calc    <   input-file >    output-file
```

or

```
echo    some    inputs  to  the calculator  |   java    
package.sub.Calc
```

But I can't seem to get it to work correctly. The goal is to be able to pass a text file into the program or write your math problems right there on the command line and pipe it in.

The program runs correctly for

```
java -cp . package.sub.Calc
```

and then having the user type in their problem and hitting enter.

If  I have a file named `input.txt` and want to call it from the command line and have the answers print out in the commandline (program is designed to `System.out.println`) how would I be entering this information in?

My current code implements a `Scanner` for `System.in`. Would I have to use anything else to get this to work? I am new to running anything in the command prompt and can't seem to get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calc calc = new Calc();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String input = "";
     List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tokens;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine().trim();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            for (String s : strs) {
                sb.append(s);
                input = sb.toString();
            }
            tokens = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
            //call calculate and reset
            calc.calculate(tokens);
            strs.clear();
            tokens.clear();
            sb.setLength(0);
            input = "";
        } else if (line.length() == 1) {
            strs.add(" ");
            strs.add(line);
            strs.add(" ");
        //manual user exit case
        } else if (line.equals("EXIT")){
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            strs.add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just taking the filename as `String` in the command line, then using that String in Java to open the file? have a look at this example http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far. What you are describing should work fine, so if there's a problem then it probably exists on your implementation.

Comment: @Tim added my main method. I'm not sure if the issue is my code or what im inputting to the command line. How would I pass in input.txt for example?

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then tell us what happens when you run your program, what inputs you use, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: in the folder before my package directory, I run `java package.sub.Calc < input.txt ? output.txt` both input and output are text files in the same directory. with input having appropriate input contents. I recieve a Error: Could not find or load main class package.sub.Calc

Comment: `echo 2 2 + | java package.sub.Calc` has the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have 2 problems.

1) You're including the `-cp` commandline option when you run the program manually, but not when you try and read from the input. You need it in both cases - that's telling *java* where to find your class file.

2) The way you are handling your input doesn't match the input you're passing in.

You only call `calculate` when you receive an empty line ( `if(line.isEmpty())` ), but something like

```
echo some inputs to the calculator | java -cp . package.sub.Calc
```

doesn't ever produce a blank line.

You either need to do:

```
printf "%s\n\n"  "some inputs to the calculator" | java -cp . package.sub.Calc
```

or change the condition that triggers a `calculate` (probably by invoking it outside of the `while` loop).

Comment: 2) I tried the printf code you have provided and I recieved a 'is not recignized as an internal or external command'

Comment: Ah, it looks like you are running on windows. In that case, the `printf` option won't work, but you can get the result you want by making sure that the file you send in has a blank line at the end.

Comment: I will have to test it on my linux comp later. In the meantime thank you! I'm new to running things via cmd prmpt so the intricacies escape me

Answer (score -1):

your input is received in your `main` method. `public static void main (String[] args)`. The `args` array is the array which will receive your input parameters IF you have ran your program as `java -cp . <main_class_pat> <arg0> <arg1> ...`

Make sure your `args` array has desired length ... and if so, your input file would be at `arg[0]`

Comment: Alkarin wants to read from _stdin_ (`System.in`), not from command line arguments.